# What affects the time to create a cluster using the parallel package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm experiencing slowness when creating clusters using the `parallel` package.

Here is a function that just creates and then stops a PSOCK cluster, with `n` nodes.

```
library(parallel)
library(microbenchmark)
f <- function(n)
{
  cl <- makeCluster(n)
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
}
microbenchmark(f(2), f(4), times = 10)
## Unit: seconds
##  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
##  f(2) 4.095315 4.103224 4.206586 5.080307 5.991463    10
##  f(4) 8.150088 8.179489 8.391088 8.822470 9.226745    10
```

My machine (a reasonably modern 4-core workstation running Win 7 Pro) is taking about 4 seconds to create a two node cluster and 8 seconds to create a four node cluster. This struck me as too slow, so I tried the same profiling on a colleague's identically specced machine, and it took one/two seconds for the two tests respectively.

This suggested I may have some odd configuration set up on my machine, or that there is some other problem.  I read the `?makeCluster` and `socketConnection` help pages, but did not see anything related to improving performance.

I had a look in the Windows Task Manager while the code was running: there was no obvious interference with anti-virus or other software, just an Rscript process running at ~17% (less than one core).

I don't know where to look to find the source of the problem. Are there any known causes of slowness with PSOCK cluster creation under Windows?

Is 8 seconds to create a 4-node cluster actually slow (by 2014 standards), or are my expectations too high?

Comment: 8 seconds is pretty slow. It takes about 1 second on my 3 years old win7 workstation.

Comment: Takes 11 seconds on my new win8 pc.

Comment: 1.6 and 3.2 seconds on my 3 year old i7 with W7.

Comment: @JT85 All the more reason for me to avoid buying a Win8 PC :-)

Comment: .634 and 1.271,and  .638 and 1.272 using snowfall package `f2(n){sfInit(parallel=T,cpus=n); sfStop()} on Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To monitor what was happening, I installed and opened [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (HT @qethanm). I also exited most of the things in my system tray like Dropbox, in order to generate less noise.  (Though in the end, this didn't make a difference.)

I then re-ran a simplified version of the R code in the question, directly from R GUI (instead of an IDE).

```
microbenchmark(f(4), times = 5)
```

After some digging, I noticed that R GUI spawns an Rscript process for each cluster that it creates (see picture).

[image: the process tree shows an Rscript instance for each node in each cluster]

After many dead ends and wild goose chases, it occurred to me that perhaps these Rscript instances weren't vanilla R.  I renamed my `Rprofile.site` file to hide it and repeated the benchmark.

This time, a 4 node cluster was created, on average, in just under a second.

**For a four node cluster, the `Rprofile.site` file (and presumably the personal startup file, `~/.Rprofile`, if it exists) gets read four times, which can slow things down considerably.  Pass `rscript_args = c("--no-init-file", "--no-site-file", "--no-environ")` to `makeCluster` to avoid this behaviour.**

Comment: Upon further inspection, it seems that the vast majority of the time spent inside my `Rprofile.site` is in the call to `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`.

Comment: How renaming Rprofile.site influences further analysis you may execute? isn't that a necessary step? Other users did not take this approach to get similar results.

Comment: Not having or using an `Rprofile.site` file just means that any options you set or variables you defined in the file won't be set/exist.